# How to change the transition type of slider with arrow and bullet (jssor)

Tags: jssor

I changed the jssor transition types (from slide to fade) by ading the folowing code :

```
 $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            },
```

This transition works correctly when the sliders auto play but when I navigate into slides using arrow or bullet the type of transition is  slide and not fade
How can resolve it ?

-the value of  _SlideshowTransitions is :

```
 var _SlideshowTransitions = [
                {$Duration:700,$Opacity:2}
             ];
```

Comment: For now, jssor slider always slides `left<->right` on demand navigation request like click on navigation `arrows/bullets/thumbnails`.

Comment: Hi any updates on this? I am facing exactly same problem